# Custom comparator -- would "<=" save a swap over "<"?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a custom multi-criteria comparator, though the multi part probably doesn't matter.  To keep it simple, let's say we're sorting arrays consisting of 3 doubles representing coordinates.

I know the go-to comparison operator is "<", but I have this nagging feeling that "<=" might save a swap if all parts are equal.  Does the sorter (e.g. std::sort) go, "Hey, if comparator returns false, I'm swapping you!", or is this incorrect assumption?  Thanks.

```
// Compare based on X, then Y, then Z
bool PointComparer(const array<double,3>& a, const array<double,3>& b)
{
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return true;
    if (a[0] > b[0]) return false;

    if (a[1] < b[1]) return true;
    if (a[1] > b[1]) return false;

    return a[2] < b[2];  // If instead was a[2] <= b[2], would it save a swap in equal case?
}
// Later sort a collection of these arrays
```

Comment: Why not just use the built in array `operator <` to do the comparison and the benchmark to make sure it is acceptable?

Comment: The designers of std::sort "have had this nagging feeling that "<=" might save a swap if all parts are equal." and considered all kinds of pathological input.

Comment: Strict weak ordering (look it up). You need to implement that. Operator<= is not that.

Comment: No need to swap `a` and `b` if `!(a < b)` and `!(b < a)` (`a` and `b` are 'equivalent')

Comment: gotcha.  I will purge all future thoughts of '<='

Comment: @JesperJuhl For completeness sake, what was attempted here is using a total order. A total order R is reflexive, transitive, and the following holds (this is called totality): For all a,b: R(a,b) or R(b,a)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use `<=` for `std::sort()` and similar standard algorithms as it does not satisfy [Compare concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) which requires [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) and violates this condition:

> For all x in S, it is not the case that x < x (irreflexivity).

so using this operator would lead to UB and it meaningless to discuss if it would prevent a swap or not.

Comment: I'm a big believer in assertions, and if I was writing `std::sort`, I'd certainly drop in something like `assert(!less(a,b) || !less(b,a))` just for good measure. (Of course that doesn't mean it's not UB.)